# I have a button in a bootrap 5 modal that is not enabled using settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have this modal, in which I put a button to close the modal, the fact is that I want to put it so that this modal can be closed, for example, in 6 seconds with setTimeout But after 6 seconds the button is not activated

This is the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="videoModalLabel">Akacia Electric</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="playerModal"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="closeBtn" disabled>Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script I use with jquery

```
 function openVideoModal() {
    $('#closeBtn').prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#closeBtn').prop('disabled', true);  
    }, 6000);

$('#videoModal').modal('show');
    playerModal = new YT.Player('playerModal', {
      height: '315',
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'DmwyO9GfL2Y', // Aquí va el ID del video que quieres reproducir
      playerVars: {
        'controls': 1,
        'rel': 0,
        'showinfo': 0
      }
    });
  }
```

And this is the card that have the button to open the modal:

```
<div class="col">
        <div class="card w-75">
        <div id="player"></div>
        
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Akacia Electric</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" onclick="openVideoModal()">Win points</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It should be `$('#closeBtn').prop('disabled', false);` in the timeout callback...

Comment: @Unmitigated thank you it work, i'm stupid hahah